# The requested URL was not found on this server. Ubuntu Server Laravel Deploy

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, deployment

when access the main index web its normal, but when access other page example like 192.16.x.xx/video it show an error url was not found.

i already setup sites-available .conf like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ServerName 192.168.xx.xxx
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Allow from all
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the .httaccess for main root folder and inside the public folder like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

and also add the index.php in the main root folder like this

```
<?php
header('Location: public/');
```

i currently setting this server must use FortiClient VPN

where is the problem ?

Comment: Using mod_rewrite requires [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) to include `FileInfo`, check if that is the case.

Comment: And [`Options`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) must include `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` (or `FollowSymLinks` at least, but the former is preferable; the latter can cause security issues in a multi-user environment.)